# Как реализовать шифрование совместимое с GPG средствами python3

Tags: python-3.x, gpg

Ранее использовал bash скрипт который собирал в интернете некоторую информацию, шифровал её с помощью  GPG и отправлял по почте. Сейчас возникла необходимость сделать полную реализацию на python3. Помогите решить вопрос с шифрованием. Нужно зашифровать файл с помощью ключа и таким алгоритмом, чтобы потом расшифровать с помощью  GPG.

Comment: То есть, вы хотите переписать GPG полностью на Питоне? Категорически не рекомендую. Есть такая штука как python-gnupg, но она, похоже, является оберткой над GPGшными бинарями.

Comment: https://github.com/isislovecruft/python-gnupg

Comment: мне python-gnupg не понравилась в работе... переписал тогда на опенссл. думаю пожно все шифрование сделать на ссл, только изменив формат структуры файла.